# amCharts: How to push a variable as String?

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I want to use the values of an Array of variables... but the interpreter said

> "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ["

for

> "li_values[w][0].toString()"

. The values in li_values[:][0] is {"height", "acc", "value" ..}

```
for (var v = 1; v < li_values[0].length; v++) {
        for(var w = 1; w < li_values.length; w++) {
                chartData.push({
                       "time" : li_values[0][v].toString(),
                       li_values[w][0].toString() : li_values[w][v].toString()
                   });
        }
}
```

Comment: I am a newbie in javascript. What is the plunker in this example. I google it... but without related info.

Comment: Plunker is an online community for creating, collaborating on and sharing your web development ideas. so u can share u r code there

Answer (score 1):

Try it in this way

```
for (var v = 1; v < li_values[0].length; v++) {
    for(var w = 1; w < li_values.length; w++) { 
        var obj = {};
        obj.time = li_values[0][v].toString();
        obj.li_values[w][0].toString() = li_values[w][v].toString(); 
        chartData.push(obj);
    }
}
```

Comment: try using obj[li_values[w][0].toString()] instead obj.li_values[w][0].toString(). it should work else try console all values in inner loop

Comment: Works! Thanks a million!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to do, but shouldn't you do it like this?:

```
for (var v = 1; v < li_values.length; v++) {
        for(var w = 1; w < li_values[v].length; w++) {
                chartData.push({
                       "time" : li_values[v][w].toString(),
                       li_values[v][w].toString() : li_values[v][w].toString()
                   });
        }
}
```

And I assume li_values is a vector which contains other vectors that contains ints or floats?

Comment: the for loops are correct in my case. The problem is 'li_values[v][w].toString()'.